# ORing controllers

Tags: power-supply, power-electronics, dc-dc-converter, redundancy

I am planning to use ORing controllers in my battery applications for N+1 redundant power supplies. But I never used them till now. I had some doubts regarding its usage. I see some ORing controller evaluation boards.
Suppose if I use two power supplies, the output of these two power supplies given to the common load bus.

I am uploading a figure that explains my application.

[image: ORing controller].

Now my doubt is after the ORing controllers getting supply from the DC/DC Converters, the voltage is being directly sent to the load bus through ORing controllers or Do I need to implement any operation of the ORing controllers. Simply, its like taking supply from DC/DC Converters and giving it to the common load bus.

Can some please give me some idea how to use ORing evaluation boards?

Low Voltage OR-ing FET Controller data sheet [ISL6146B](https://www.renesas.com/us/en/document/dst/isl6146-datasheet)

Comment: This may likely have unstable  results without current sensing each supply, for current sharing and sensing load current unless you expect the one with a 1mV higher current to handle all the load.  Current sharing designs might also demand a pre-load to avoid regulation issues.  But some designs may work.

Comment: You need to be sure if one is powered the other does not drive power into it and destroy it. I have seen this happen several times. You can  isolate them with P-MOSFETS, they will do a nice job and unlike diodes stay cool.

Comment: Seems pretty obvious from the data sheet.